# How can I find the radius of curvature of a pipe when given the angle?

Tags: geometry, curvature, angle

I am given a pipe with a 3mm diameter with walls of nearly infinite thinness (so the impact is not affected the the thickness of the pipe) that has something travelling down the center of it in a line. How can I find the minimum radius of curvature of the center line of this pipe such that when the line intersects the wall it will not have an angle greater than 69 degrees?

I have tried making a triangle that connects the point where the curve starts, the impact point, and the center of the curve, but that only tells me the angles of that triangle, leaving the sides all unknown.

I have found that the length of the outer arc within the triangle has a length of 1.2 times the radius, but again, that isn't helpful. I have no other ideas about how I would even proceed with this and searching online for something I can extrapolate the answer from has been fruitless.

[image: Pipe Problem Image]

The goal is to then find the radius of the circle that is created by curving at that rate.

Added explanation from comments:
The problem can essentially be boiled down to: Two lines are travelling parallel to each other 1.5 mm apart along the x-plane. At some arbitrary point, the line below curves up and intersects the line above it, creating an angle of 69 degrees from the tangent of the curving line. If the line continues curving at the same speed to create a circle, what is the radius of that circle (i.e. the radius of curvature).

Comment: This question seems interesting, but I am personally not able to understand it completely – perhaps I am just too dense. This angle, which you are trying to bound above, it is between what and what exactly? Some pictures, if possible, I think would clarify everything.

Comment: I will work on a picture for this now, but also try to explain in verbally in the meantime. The problem can essentially be boiled down to: Two lines are travelling parallel to each other 1.5 mm apart along the x-plane. At some arbitrary point, the line below curves up and intersects the line above it, creating an angle of 69 degrees from the tangent of the curving line. If the line continues curving at the same speed to create a circle, what is the radius of that circle (i.e. the radius of curvature).

Comment: Two straight lines $L_{1}, L_{2}$ are running parallel to each other in the plane. At some instant, the line $L_{2}$ below curves up, eventually intersecting $L_{1}$ (which remained straight) in a way such that the angle between $L_{1}$ and the straight line tangent to $L_{2}$ at the point of intersection is 69 degrees. Correct? If so, then, if you for example don't restrict the rate at which $L_{2}$ curves up (i.e. its second derivative), then we can make $L_{2}$ have arbitrary radius of curvature at the moment of its intersection with $L_{1}$ (continued)

Comment: For instance, $L_{2}$ might just curve up really fast, and then, before intersecting $L_{1}$, start behaving like a straight line (of slope $\arctan{69º}$), therefore intersecting $L_{1}$ at an angle of 69 degrees, but with an infinite radius of curvature.

Comment: @wet That is a possibility, but in this case we are to assume that the rate at which L2 curves is constant from the moment it begins curving to the moment it touches L1. Anything beyond that point is inconsequential.

Comment: EDIT: OK. I see that you've imposed the constraint of constant second derivative. I'll think about it.

Comment: I think that there is actually only one way in which $L_{2}$ can curve up so as to intersect $L_{1}$ at the desired angle of 69 degrees, i.e. there is no maximum nor minimum radius of curvature, there is only one possible such radius $R$. I'm thinking specifically that $R = \tfrac{1.5}{1-\cos{21º}}$. Will make an illustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some visual guidance:[image]

We thus must have that

$$ R = 1.5 + R \cos{69º} $$

Comment: How would this answer change if the walls of the tube are not infinitely thin, and if they are made of some elastic material?

Answer (score 3):

The circular arc before hitting the wall describes a sector of a circle with radius $r$ and angle $\theta$. One radius of the sector is straight vertical, and the other intersects the wall perpendicular to the wall. We therefore have
$$\theta + 90 + (90-69) = 180$$
and so $\theta = 69$ degrees. Finally
$$r\cos\theta = r-1.5$$
or
$$r = \frac{1.5}{1-\cos 69^\circ} \approx ~2.34\ \mathrm{mm}$$

(Sanity check: if $69^\circ$ were $90^\circ$ instead, the above would give $r=1.5\ \mathrm{mm}$, which is as expected.)

Comment: could you make a sketch? I really can't get "One radius of the sector is straight vertical, and **the other intersects the wall perpendicular to the wall**".

Comment: @KM259 I actually got messed up with the signs and complementary angles with that answer, and intended $R = \tfrac{1.5}{1-\cos{69º}}$ really. I'll post a picture now.

Answer (score 0):

To find neutral axis radius of curvature $r$ with tube radius $R$ and thickness $t$:

$$r = \frac{1.5}{1-\cos 69^\circ} \cdot \frac{R}{R+t/2} $$